# んです Conjugation

Tags: grammar, particle-の, copula, no-da

We recently learned んです form in class and I think I understand when to use it. But I'm a little unclear about how conjugation of it works.

んです　itself doesn't get conjugated, right? You conjugate the verb/noun/adjective that comes before it.

- 頭がいたいんです。
- 風邪をひいたんです。
- 本が好きなんです。

And, as with な adjectives, な also gets added after nouns. But how would this work in the past tense?

Comment: Be aware that the ん here is a contraction of の.  The です is just the regular copula ("is" verb): plain form is だ, plain past is だった, polite form is です, polite past is でした.

Answer (score 3):

> んです itself doesn't get conjugated, right?

んです（≂ のです; particle の + copula です） conjugates to:

んです、んでした、んでしょう、(んでして、) -- polite
んだ、んだった、んだろう、んで、んなら -- plain

> And, as with な adjectives, な also gets added after nouns. But how would this work in the past tense?

You replace な with だった, as in:

花**な**んです。→ 花**だった**んです。